# URL Amigável com mais de um parâmetro com .htaccess php

Tags: php, htaccess, url-amigável

estou tendo problemas com minha url amigável, tenho um código que já funciona, porém para um diretório especifico.

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  index.php?url=$1
```

**index.php**

```
$url = (isset($_GET['url'])) ? $_GET['url'] : 'mdjr_home';

$arq_perm = array('mdjr_home','mdjr_contatos','mdjr_orcamento',
    'mdjr_portifolio','mdjr_quem_somos','mdjr_videos','mdjr_teste');

$pasta = "producoes/page_mdjr/pages_menu";

if (substr_count($url,'/') == 0)
{
    $url = explode('/',$url);
    $page = (file_exists("{$pasta}/".$url[0].'.php') && in_array($url[0],$arq_perm)) ? $url[0] : "404";
    $id = intval(isset($url[1]));

}elseif(substr_count($url,'/') == 0)
{
    $page = (file_exists("{$pasta}/".$url.'.php') && in_array($url[1],$arq_perm)) ? $url : "404";
    $id = 0;

    // echo $page;
}

require ("{$pasta}/{$page}.php");
```

Só adicionado isso ao meu menu .php e minha url amigável do menu funciona,, porém no meu home que é a page principal tenho alguns cards ele me gera essas urls:

```
mdjr/producoes/controller/controller.php?card=0
mdjr/producoes/controller/controller.php?card=1
mdjr/producoes/controller/controller.php?card=2
mdjr/producoes/controller/controller.php?card=3
mdjr/producoes/controller/controller.php?card=4
```

pois ao clicar ele abre o link da pagina

```
mdjr/producoes/controller/controller.php
```

onde digo o que será exibido em cada coisa, 
    porém não sei o que fazer para tanto o código php no meu index.php como o do meu .htaccess funcione ate incluí alguns desses códigos no .htaccess mas não deu certo. tentei adicionar :

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/?(.*)\/?$ index.php?url=$1&card=$2
RewriteRule ^producoes/controller/([a-z0-9-]+)/([0-9]+)/?$/controller.php?url=$2&card=$1 [NC]

RewriteRule ^producoes/controller/.*?$ controller.php?card=$1
```

Junto com o já existente mas nada funciona, retorna sempre a pagina de erro, sem isso a pagina é aberta normalmente e funciona, mas ao adicionar esses códigos dão erro.

Comment: Qual é exatamente o modelo de URL que precisa. Posta um exemplo de como gostaria que fosse a URL

Comment: no momento ao clicar no link esse é o endereço completo                               http://localhost/mdjr/producoes/controller/controller.php?card=0                            gostaria que ficasse depois do dominio/mdjr/controller           somente isso, independe do id que eu clicasse, ou poderia ser com o depois sem problemas, mas nao sei se tudo iso depende so da programação php ou somnete do .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

Baseado no seu comentário, você gostaria de montar a url na seguinte estrutura: `dominio/mdjr/controller/(id ou não)`, correto? E essa url apontaria pra controller.php.

Poderia usar isso no **.htaccess**:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^mdjr/controller\/?$ controller.php?card=0 [NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^mdjr/controller/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)\/?$ controller.php?card=$1 [NC,QSA]
```

**controller.php**

```
$card = $_GET['card']
```

Porém, vi que em seu código existe um array com nomes de alguma coisa. Vai me informando melhor pra ir atualizando a resposta caso não seja somente isso.

Comment: alterei o meu .htaccess  acrescentei o codigo acima           RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  index.php?url=$1

RewriteRule ^mdjr/controller\/?$ controller.php?card=0 [NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^mdjr/controller/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)\/?$ controller.php?card=$1 [NC,QSA                  e ficou assim, porém a agora da erro, sim, no meu index.php tenho um array                 $arq_perm = array('mdjr_home','mdjr_contatos','mdjr_orcamento',
    'mdjr_portifolio','mdjr_quem_somos','mdjr_videos','mdjr_teste');

Comment: E  ele pegar o nome dos meus arquivos  menu por exemplo que esta em  producoes/page_mdjr/pages_menu/mdjr_home                      ele deixa as url do meu menu amigavel, mas como o meu controller.php esta dois niveis a cima, acho que meu codigo php nao serve para ele! na verdade peguei esse codigo na internet e modifiquei para mim.

Comment: Não é ideal utilizar `(.*)` em htaccess. Isso pode ser o motivo do seu erro. Você testou apenas com as regras que coloquei?

Comment: fiz as alterações coloquei somente as regras que vc colocou a principal funciona, mas ao clicar  no menu da erro, pagina nao encontrada, com se o codigo php nao funcionasse, como sei que no codigo ele busta pelo parametro url para as minhas paginas do menu, então alteri o tudo que tiha como card para url mas memo assim nada, pois talvez melho rdeixa parametr url para o menu e card para os link dos card

Comment: se eu deixar essa regra as url amigavel dos meni volta a fumcionar, como ficaria essa regra sem asterisco?                                                                                                              RewriteRule ^(.*)$  index.php?url=$1        as url do link de controller permanecem ainda  assim http://localhost/mdjr/producoes/controller/controller.php?card=0               e eu queria que ficasse http://dominio/mdjr/controller/ com ou sem id opcional  lembrando que os arquivos de meus menus estao em outro diretorio onde o codigo php

Comment: vai buscar eles nesse caminho   $pasta = "producoes/page_mdjr/pages_menu";   e o controller.php se econtra em  producoes/controller/controller.php       chamo ao clicar nesse link                           <a href="../mdjr/producoes/controller/controller.php?card=<?=$count++ ?>" target="_blank">  que fica em minha home

Comment: Estou ainda tentando entender sua lógica. Você quer que fique assim: `dominio/mdjr/controller/(id ou não)`. Mas como espera saber qual página do array incluir? Você precisaria de mais um parâmetro, como por exemplo: `dominio/mdjr/controller/pagina_menu/(id ou não)`. Faria sentido isso? Ambos serão tratados no `index.php`, correto?

Comment: sim, talvez eu tenha pensado errado mesmo, é como meu menu.php esta varios nives a baixo tipo mdjr/producoes/page1/page1/home.php e com url amigavel ficou so  dominio/mdjr/home pensei que se eu simplesmente usar um arquivo controller.php para imprimir para mim seria uma boa ja que nao seria nenhum menu não qui criar outra pagina no menu, e com esta mais  niveis acima ficaria mais facil por exemplo ele esta eem mdjr (obs é a pasta do projeto) mdjr/controller/controller.php pensei que daria para deixar algo do tipo mdjr/controller

Comment: trocarei esse nome posteriormente para nao aparecer assim na url, tudo bem se fica mdjr/controller/controller  eu irei mudar esse nome oara fica melhor

Comment: Sem problemas, estamos ajustando para melhorar o projeto. Veja bem, com URL amigável, vc pode inclusive eliminar `mdjr` e `controller` da url, ficando por exemplo: `dominio.com/seu_menu/(id ou não)`. Já que você gostaria de tratar tudo em controller.php. Seria tranquilo fazer isso. Deixe me saber se é assim que gostaria então atualizo o código.

Comment: como não tenho tanta experiencia o que eu fiz, deixei o arquivo index.php com o codigo para url amigavel, e fiz isso no meu menu.php <?php  require_once __DIR__ . '/../../../index.php';?>                                   como na minha home tem uns cards co alguns links que é gerado dinamicamente com uma sequencia de numero criei a pasta e arquivo controller so para tratar de exibir as imagens que pego recusirvamente usando o Interator do php ai conforme o link que clico com parametro card=0 ou card=1 ele exibe o que quero que esta dentro do controller com alguns if's,qual o mais correto?

Comment: apareceu mensagem dizendo que tem muitos comentarios, se vc achar melhor assim,  por mim tudo bem, mas e preferir me ajudar no chat sem problemas também!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Podemos ir para o chat sim lá pelas 14h

Comment: nao posso mover haha mas ainda aguardo sua ajuda, para me ajudar entender o que estou errando

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191231/dm707-joannes